# Algorithm to reshape a deformed cube to normal cube with max size (furthest vertex)

Tags: c#, algorithm, 3d

I am wondering if there is an algorithm, or a mathematical function that starts from a deformed cube, gets the furthest vertices and reshapes the cube to a normal cube pased on the furthest vertices.

To make my question more clear, have a look at the following picture:

So I start with a deformed cube on the left and I want to transform it such that it will look like the second cube on the right. Since the vertex (2,2,3) is the furthest of them all, I believe it's correct to state that all other vertices should have the value 3 as their coördinates, which will result in a cube on the right?

[image]

To achieve this, is there an existing formula that I can apply in my programming language? Or should I write my own, something like: *"loop over all vertices to find the furthest one. Then, from this vertex it's x,y,z coördinates which has the highest value (in this case z:3). Then put this value as the corresponding x,y,z coördinates of all other vertices*?

**update**
Ofcourse I am aware that the same should apply if the furthest vertex has a negative coördinate, but this can easily be calculated.

Comment: Two things: it's called coordinate (sry for the grammar nazi, but this one really bugged me). And you should start by making a clear definition of what furthest means in this context. E.g. distance from the center of the cube, the origin of the coordinate system, longest diagonal, etc..

Comment: Sorry for my mistake but my native language is not English. The furthest vertex is the one with the largest distance away from the origin coordinate system.

Answer (score 0):

no `3` is not the size because your deformed cube's center is not `(0,0,0)` !!!  You should clarify what properties you need to preserve.

- size
- position
- orientation (of what)

There are more ways to do this but if you need to preserve all of the above (with constrains to max the size):

1. **compute center (avg point)**
2. **find out biggest diagonal and from that compute half size of your cube.**
3. **compute basis vectors**

   so just edges of your cube in 3 axises and set them to correct size and also make them perpendicular exploiting **cross product**.
4. **construct new vertexes**

   so just translate from center along each basis vector to both directions and that is it. In case you do not need to preserve rotation you can skip **#3** and use `(1,0,0),(0,1,0),(0,0,1)` as basis vectors directly.